# Sharing Data between Sibling Components using Shared Service returning empty in Angular

Tags: angular, observable, angularfire, angular-services

I am attempting to share a string between two sibling components within Angular, but it does not appear to be working for me.

I have two components, `auth.component.ts` and `update.component.ts`. I then have a service called `shared.service.ts`.

**EDIT 2:**
I am including the entire **shared.services.ts** file as per the recommendation in the comments.

**shared.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SharedService {

  private useridSource = new BehaviorSubject('empty');

  useridMessage$ = this.useridSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  sendUserId(userId:string) {
    this.useridSource.next(userId);
  }
}
```

The purpose of the `auth` component is to allow a user to login/sign up via firebase's authentication methods. I then retrieve the User's Unique ID and want to pass that string on to the `update.ts` component so that it can create a node under that name in the Firebase Real Time Database. Please note that I am also using the [Angular Fire Library](https://github.com/angular/angularfire) when working with firebase.

Here are the snippets of code from **auth.component.ts**

```js
  //I store the unique ID created by firebase in this string
  userId?:string;

  //I inject the AngularFireAuth from the Angular Fire library as well as my Shared Service 
  constructor(public auth: AngularFireAuth, private sharedService: SharedService ) { }

  //the user logs in or signs up using google
  login() {
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }

  //this function sets the userId string - if I console.log() this string, it prints out correctly
  printUserId() {
    this.auth.authState.subscribe( authState => {
      this.currentAuth = authState;
      this.userId = this.currentAuth.uid;
    })
  }

  //I use this function to send the data via the shared service when a button is pressed in the HTML file. 
  sendUserData(){
    if(this.userId) {
      console.log(this.userId);
      this.sharedService.sendUserId(this.userId);
    } else {
      console.log("User Id has not been set");
    }
  }
```

In the **auth.component.html** file, I send the data to the service by:

```html
  <button (click)="sendUserData()"> Send Current User </button>
```

In **update.component.ts**, I received the data and want to print it out.

```js
  //string to receive the data in 
  userId?:string;

  //inject the shared service. The CrowboxdbService is another service I use to interact with firebase
  constructor(private cbservice: CrowboxdbService, private sharesService: SharedService) {
  }

  //this function is invoked when a button is pressed in the view (HTML file)
  getUserId(){
    this.sharesService.useridMessage$.subscribe(x => {
      this.userId = x;
      console.log(this.userId);
    }  
    );
  }
```

In the **update.component.html**

```html
<button (click)="getUserId()">Get User ID </button>
<h1>User Id is: {{userId}}</h1>
```

So when I attempt to send the data through `sendUserData()` in the **auth.component.ts** file, it works. I am able to print the User Id in the console window as well. In **update.component.ts**, however, when I subscribe to the observable, I still receive "empty". Does this mean that it is not changing the value?

I have tried subscribing to the observable in `ngOnInit()` in both the `ts` files but that still does not return the proper value. Am I missing something? I have been following [this tutorial](https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/).

**EDIT 1:**
Important note (I think?), the two components also serve as two different routes. Here are the routes set up in **app-routing.module.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path:'', component:TestUpdateComponent },
  { path:'auth', component:AuthComponentComponent }
];
```

Comment: Why can't you use `get` and `set` methods in the sharedSerive? set the userid to sharedService using `set` method and you can subscribe to `get` in all your components. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Lenzman I'll give that a shot. But won't it essentially be the same thing?

Comment: in the auth.component.ts file you are printing from the callBack of this.auth.authState right?

Comment: Printing to the console? No, I am printing the User Id to the console in `sendUserData()` function. So basically I click a button that invokes `printUserId()` and it after setting the variable `this.userId` it prints it to the HTML file `{{userId}}` of the auth component.

Comment: I should also add that the two components are two separate routes in angular. Would this make a difference?

Comment: @HamzaQureshi IF each route is lazy loaded it may make a difference.  You don't have injectable metadata specified on the service.  Where did you set up the provider?

Comment: add the full service file @HamzaQureshi

Comment: @JeffryHouser Ah I did not know that. I didn't set up the provider but I have done so right now. In the `app.module.ts` file I have set it: `  providers: [SharedService]`. This does not fix this.

Comment: @skyBlue I will edit this into the main question

Comment: I have now realised that passing data through components when they are on separate routes requires a different solution. I will be looking through other guides for this.

Comment: No specifically, I have subscribed to an observable in a sharedService from other modules. So it should work

Comment: @HamzaQureshi Let me know if you want that as an answer

Comment: I threw together a sample showing how to use a provider to share data between two components on different routes: https://github.com/Reboog711/JeffryHouserBlogSamplesSource/tree/master/2021/11/ShareDataBetweenComponentsOnDifferentRoutes . I don't have a good feel for why it isn't working in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was actually to do with the fact that I was attempting to share data between components that are in different routes. As a result, these are unrelated components and I could not use the standard methods of sharing data (e.g. from parent to child or between sibling components).

I followed the third example from [this website](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/12/3-simple-ways-to-share-data-through.html). I created a simple service through `ng g s shared` command. I imported this service into my **app.module.ts** file and included it as one of the `providers`.

The **shared.service.ts** file is very simple, as I only want to pass one string:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SharedService {

  public userId:any;

  constructor() { }
}
```

Then, in **auth.component.ts**, the file which needed to send the data, I had a function that was executed upon the click of a button. This function checked if the string in question had been set previously (by the user logging in in this case). If he string was set, it then set the string in the provider file and navigated to the receiver component page.

```js
  //function is invoked by a button in the view page 
  sendUserData(){
    if (this.userId) {
      this.sharedService.userId = this.userId;
      this.router.navigate(['data']);
    } else {
      console.log("User Id has not been set");
    }
  }
```

To receive the data in **update.component.ts**, I had a simple function that was also executed upon the click of a button:

```js
  getUserId(){
    this.userId = this.sharesService.userId;
    console.log(this.userId);    
  }
```

And this prints out the value. If I am not mistaken, this method also makes the variable globally available to all components that have access to this specific provider.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I checked your code and the problem may caused by lots of reasons but I *think* the problem is that you provided this service in multiple modules.

Make sure that you only provide this service in one module that declared both components or in the `app.module.ts`

My suggestion is to create a `components.module.ts` and declare all your components there so you can import it where ever you want.

I also recommend you to declare a public variable in the service instead of this confusing setters and getters so you can update it every where and it will update in other places.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for going through my code. Both components are using the same service and everything is through the `app.module.ts` file. I don't have any other module files just yet. I'll look to changing it to a public variable